# Is it possible to randomize the row output of a matrix field?

Tags: matrix

I would like to use a parameter like orderby="random" on a matrix field to randomize the order of the row output.

```
{matrix_field orderby="random"}
  {row_title}
{/matrix_field}
```

I tried this, but got a MySQL error.  Is this possible?

Comment: What type of mysql error did you get?

Comment: Without testing I'm quite sure this is correct. What error are you getting?

Comment: MySQL error was Unknown column 'random' in 'order clause' because you can't set random via the orderby parameter. The answer below is correct!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually have to do sort="random" in Matrix. It's not like channel:entries in that way.

Comment: I just looked it up a minute ago and could have sworn I saw it under orderby as well as sort. Either the docs just changed or I'm seeing double: voting for the latter.

Comment: Yeah, the old docs used to have all this info and more, but the new ones are sorely lacking :(  Thanks for the help!